# Can't install scion-browser on Mac OSX

Tags: haskell, cabal, eclipse-fp

`cabal install scion-browser` gives:

```
[ 6 of 23] Compiling Scion.PersistentBrowser.Query ( src/Scion/PersistentBrowser/Query.hs, dist/build/scion-browser/scion-browser-tmp/Scion/PersistentBrowser/Query.o )

src/Scion/PersistentBrowser/Query.hs:258:58:
    No instance for (MonadResource IO)
      arising from a use of `get'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MonadResource IO)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: Just dc <- get declId
    In the expression:
      do { Just dc <- get declId;
           getDbModule dc }
    In an equation for `getDbModule':
        getDbModule (DbConstructor _ _ declId)
          = do { Just dc <- get declId;
                 getDbModule dc }
```

and some other info:

```
$ ghc-pkg list mtl
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.4.2/lib/ghc-7.4.2/package.conf.d
   mtl-2.1.2
/Users/eric/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.4.2/package.conf.d
$ ghc-pkg list transformers
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.4.2/lib/ghc-7.4.2/package.conf.d
   transformers-0.3.0.0
/Users/eric/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.4.2/package.conf.d
$ ghc-pkg list haskeline
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.4.2/lib/ghc-7.4.2/package.conf.d
/Users/eric/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.4.2/package.conf.d
   haskeline-0.7.0.3
```

Comment: Is GHC 7.4.2 the one that installs with the OS X Haskell Platform?

Comment: Yeah, I used homebrew to install haskell-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, see https://github.com/JPMoresmau/scion-class-browser/issues/4. Will be fixed in the next release (maybe I'll release this week around the 15th December 2012)